# How to use etcd v3 restful api to watch

Tags: rest, api, etcd, etcd3

i am trying to watch key with etcdv3 restful api,following [etcd/Documentation/dev-guide/api_grpc_gateway.md](https://github.com/coreos/etcd/blob/master/Documentation/dev-guide/api_grpc_gateway.md),but it seems not work well with watch.

```
 curl http://localhost:2379/v3beta/watch \
      -X POST -d '{"create_request": {"key":"Zm9v"} }'

 curl http://localhost:2379/v3beta/watch \
      -X POST -d '{"create_request": {"key":"Zm9v"} }'
 #{"header":{"cluster_id":"7016043442779247867","member_id":"5993310732371594633","revision":"2","raft_term":"2"}}
```

the watch will not have a response.

this is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"

services:
    etcd:
        image: quay.io/coreos/etcd:latest
        command: >
            /usr/local/bin/etcd
            --name node1
            --initial-advertise-peer-urls http://${HOST}:2380
            --listen-peer-urls http://0.0.0.0:2380
            --advertise-client-urls http://${HOST}:2379
            --listen-client-urls http://0.0.0.0:2379
            --initial-cluster node1=http://${HOST}:2380
            --debug
        expose:
            - 2379
            - 2380
        ports:
            - "2379:2379"
            - "3380:2380"
```

Comment: meet the same problem. while watching the key, and then put a key, but curl watching not return.

Comment: one of my colleague solve this problem. try `curl --no-buffer`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
$ curl --no-buffer http://localhost:2379/v3beta/watch \
      -X POST -d '{"create_request": {"key":"Zm9v"} }'
```

Also refer to this awesome article: [HTTP Streaming (or Chunked vs Store & Forward)](https://gist.github.com/CMCDragonkai/6bfade6431e9ffb7fe88)

Answer (score 0):

You can see the response once you stop etcd or you have enough number of events. I think it is due to the timing of buffer flush.